# How to get specific part of string in php using regex?

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

I have product names in an array,

```
$productArr = array("Dell Inspiron 15 3521 Laptop CDC/ 2GB/ 500GB/ Linux Black Matte Textured Finish","Dell Inspiron 15 3521 Laptop CDC/ 4GB/ 500GB/ Win8 Black","Nikon D90 DSLR (Black) with AF-S 18-105mm VR Kit Lens");
```

I want to get the output like,

```
$productModArr = array("Dell Inspiron 15 3521","Dell Inspiron 15 3521","Nikon D90")
```

And then i need to remove the duplicate string,

```
$productModArr = array("Dell Inspiron 15 3521","Nikon D90")
```

I tried `substr` and `strpos` but those are not working in my case.

Comment: Well then you would have to define when the name ends.

Comment: Add a delimiter while inserting the name of the laptop in the first play and then use that delimiter to cut the string. Otherwise you can go for the dictionnary approach but it won't handle laptops you won't have filled in the array.

Comment: I'd suggest RegEx for the first part http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php and array_unique http://php.net/manual/de/function.array-unique.php for the second part

Comment: @Rizier123 @ Answers_Seeker Thank you,but  i got the product names through feed,so i have to create product catelog with modified product names.

Comment: @JaGo Thank you,can you please help me with the first part,i can't get the exact preg_match as my product names have no specific ending.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the custom PHP function below (employing Regex) to produce your desired output as outlined in your question above.

Depending on the patterns you want to match in your product feed, you may need to tweak the Regex matching pattern a little.

```
function getProductNames ($productArr) {

$countproductArr = count($productArr);
for ($i = 0; $i < $countproductArr; $i++) {
$productModArr[] = preg_replace('/^([^0-9]*)([0-9]+)(\s[0-9]+)?(.*)/', '$1$2$3', $productArr[$i]);
}

$productModArr = array_unique($productModArr);
$productModArr = array_values($productModArr);
return $productModArr;
}

$productModArr = getProductNames($productArr);
```

***Explanation of the Regex:***

```
/ [... match goes here... ] /
```

`^` - start of match

`([^0-9]*)` - [first capture group] any non-numerical character, any number of times

`([0-9]+)` - [second capture group] any numerical character, from 1 to any number of times

`(\s[0-9]+)?` - [third (optional) capture group] a space followed by any numerical character, from 1 to any number of times

`(.*)` - any number of characters any number of times following the third (optional) capture group

## =======

**Update**

Replacing the relevant line in the function above with:

```
$productModArr[] = preg_replace('/^([^0-9]*)([^\s]+)(\s[A-Z]?[0-9]+)?(.*)/', '$1$2$3', $productArr[$i]);
```

may be a better match for the product name and odel number in more instances.

Comment: If i have these type of strings as well in array, Toshiba Satellite L50-B I3010,Lenovo Z50-70 Ideapad what can i add in pattern?

Comment: At this point, you'll need to give us some kind of formal description of the point where you want each string to end. For instance, why do you want to the Toshiba string to end after I3010 but not after L50-B? And why do you want the Lenovo string to end after Ideapad but not after Z50-70? What distinguishes the elements you want to keep in each string from the elements you wish to discard?

Comment: Sorry,i don't need ideapad.Actually i am trying to get the product name with model number.

Comment: Your script is working fine in most of the cases but if i have a products like HP 15-g221AU (Notebook),Acer Aspire E5-571-56UR Notebook it is matching upto HP 15, Acer Aspire E5 only.I need the complete model number like Acer Aspire E5-571-56UR.

Comment: That ought to be possible. Let me rack my brains and see what I can come up with for you...

Comment: Okay, I've added an update above with an alternative regex which should match all the examples you have mentioned in the comments as well as the original two.

Comment: Updated code worked for all types of strings i have,thank you so much for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for your 3 examples, but since there is no standard in such product names there are probably a lot of situations where the format is different.

```
$productArr = array("Dell Inspiron 15 3521 Laptop CDC/ 2GB/ 500GB/ Linux Black Matte Textured Finish","Dell Inspiron 15 3521 Laptop CDC/ 4GB/ 500GB/ Win8 Black","Nikon D90 DSLR (Black) with AF-S 18-105mm VR Kit Lens");
 $newArr = array();
foreach($productArr as $str){
  $pattern = "/[a-zA-Z\ ]*[ A-Z]?[0-9 ]*/";
  preg_match($pattern, $str,$match);
  $newArr[] = $match[0];
}

$result = array_unique($newArr);
print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thank you.I need help for these type of strings as well, Toshiba Satellite L50-B I3010,Lenovo Z50-70.

Answer (score 0):

In my battery of test strings, I have included all sample strings that you have mentioned in the question and/or in comments.

My pattern will assume that you want to retain the substring from the start of the each string to the end of the first space-separated sequence of strings containing a digit.  This is as difficult to explain in plain English as it is to write as a regular expression. :)

Pattern Explanation: [Pattern & Replacement Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cGqAUw/1)

```
/                           #opening pattern delimiter
^                           #match from the start of the string
\D*                         #match zero or more characters that are not a digit
(?: [a-z\d-]*\d[a-z\d-]*)+  #match zero or more letters,digits,hyphens followed by a digit followed by zero or more letters,digits,hyphens
\K                          #restart the fullstring match (to avoid using a capture group)
.*                          #match remainder of the string
/                           #closing pattern delimiter
i                           #case-insensitive pattern modifier
```

Code: ([PHP Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ec0c7856b9e3aebf40829ea50b87f8256a4977a7))

```
$productArr=[
    'Dell Inspiron 15 3521 Laptop CDC/ 2GB/ 500GB/ Linux Black Matte Textured Finish',
    'Dell Inspiron 15 3521 Laptop CDC/ 4GB/ 500GB/ Win8 Black',
    'Nikon D90 DSLR (Black) with AF-S 18-105mm VR Kit Lens',
    'Toshiba Satellite L50-B I3010',
    'Lenovo Z50-70',
    'Apple',
    'HP 15-g221AU (Notebook)',
    'Acer Aspire E5-571-56UR Notebook'
];
var_export(array_flip(array_flip(preg_replace('/^\D*(?: [a-z\d-]*\d[a-z\d-]*)+\K.*/i','',$productArr))));
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 'Dell Inspiron 15 3521',
  2 => 'Nikon D90',
  3 => 'Toshiba Satellite L50-B I3010',
  4 => 'Lenovo Z50-70',
  5 => 'Apple',
  6 => 'HP 15-g221AU',
  7 => 'Acer Aspire E5-571-56UR',
)
```

p.s. I am using a double call of `array_flip()` because:

1. It will not damage your values.
2. It operates faster than `array_unique()`.
3. It allows the entire method to be chained together in one line.

(You are welcome to use `array_unique()` if you wish -- same, same.)